# Статическая компиляция Qt из исходного кода

Tags: linux, qt, qtcreator

Система: Debian 8.
Итак, мне необходимо собрать Qt Creator статически. Что делаю:

1. Устанавливаю необходимые зависимости

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential ^libxcb.* libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libfontconfig1-dev
   ```
2. Скачиваю и распаковываю исходники

   ```
   $ wget https://github.com/qt/qt/archive/4.8.zip + распаковка
   ```
3. Распаковал в /home/user_name/. Перехожу туда с помощью cd
4. Конфигурирую с опцией статической сборки

   ```
   $ ./configure -platform linux-g++ -release -static -fontconfig -opensource -confirm-license
   ```
5. Собираю

   ```
   $ make
   ```
6. И устанавливаю

   ```
   $ sudo make install
   ```

Если я всё верно понял, то в систему должен установится Qt Creator статически, т.е. свои проекты я могу собирать единым файлом. Однако, в списках всех программ (dpgk) qt отсутствует. Как его запустить? Или я просто делаю неверно что-то или чего-то не понимаю? 
Скомпилированные файлы находятся здесь:

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.7/
```

Подскажите, как грамотно собрать QT из исходников(обязательно статически, чтобы я мог наконец все используемые библиотеки вшить в исполняемый файл) и самое главное - запустить?

Comment: Вам не нужен статически собранный Qt Creator, Вам надо Qt статически собирать. По статической сборке Qt 4.8 море ссылок в поиске.

Comment: @ixSci судя по ссылке на репозиторий, откуда я выгружаю исходный код, я собираю qt таки. Но, повторюсь, он собрался, что делать дальше? Я читал, но обычно все заканчивается на сборке qt и все. Как это цеплять к creator не расписано.

Comment: QtCreator это просто IDE. Если у Вас статически собранные библиотеки, то при сборке проекта они будут скомпанованы с единый бинарный файл, вне зависимости от того, используете Вы QtCreator или нет. Почитайте что такое статические библиотеки в C/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, отвечаю на собственный вопрос, ибо так никто и не помог и пришлось разбираться. Для статической компиляции QT нужно следующее:
Установить Qt Creator. Посмотреть в about версию используемого Qt. 
Иногда, для сборки нужны дополнительные зависимости. Устанавливаем, если надо:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential ^libxcb.* libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libfontconfig1-dev
```

Далее пройти [сюда](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/), выбрать нужную версию и в папке single скачать архив с исходниками:

```
qt-everywhere-src-"ВЕРСИЯ".tar.xz
```

Следующим пунктом будет скачивание исходников, любыми способами, и распаковкой в конкретную папку(к примеру):

```
/home/USER-NAME/qt_source/
```

После того, как распаковка закончится, создаем папку выходного каталога скомпилированного Qt:

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/Qt5_st
```

Переходим в каталог распаковки:

```
cd  /home/USER-NAME/qt_source/
```

Далее запускаем конфигуратор сборки:

```
./configure -platform linux-g++ -release -static -fontconfig -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -prefix /usr/lib/Qt5_st
```

, где -static - это то, ради чего всё затевалось. Статическая сборка проектов.
Остальное можно посмотреть в документации.

И затем выполняем команды сборки и последующей установки Qt в систему:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Ждем некоторое количество времени, всё зависит от конфигурации ПК, где происходит компиляция.

После компиляции в созданной папке /usr/lib/Qt5_st/bin будет лежать файл qmake, к которому надо указать путь в самой QT (Инструменты-Параметры-Профили QT-Добавить - и выбрать файл qmake из папки /usr/lib/Qt5_st/bin)

Далее надо нажать применить - перейти на вкладку комплекты - нажать добавить, внизу в списке выбрать профиль QT и выбрать созданный на предыдущем шаге профиль. Осталось только нажать применить и ОК. Можно закрыть настройки, и добавить профиль к текущему проекту. Для этого надо нажать CTRL + 5 и добавитьк проекту новый вариант сборки.

И на этом всё, при компиляции проекта на выходе будет единый бинарный файл, включающий в себя все используемые библиотеки Qt.